# Random distribution which statistical method

Tags: python, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

After K-means, I am iterating over many files consists of tables, mostly are 3X3. Some of them with "0" elements inside cells but most of them aren't. I read that chi2_contingencycouldn't be used if zero appears inside one or two of the cells. What method should I use if for example I am trying to find where df1 is differently distributed than df3? // or df2 different from df1.. (using python) E.g of tables:

```
Cluster |df1  |df2  |df3 
0       |14   |20    |100
1       |1    |3     |75
2       |0    |1     |12
3       |2    |2     |48

Cluster     |df1  |df2    |df3 
    0       |9    |2      |32
    1       |3    |3      |4
    2       |5    |21     |199
```

Pard of code chisquare related (no errors but isn't the right calculation):

```
e2 = frame[['df1', 'df2', 'df3']]
            stat, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(e2)
```

Comment: yates correction for continuity is for 2 $\times$ 2 tables.

Comment: So how does I ran it without any problems? what it does when I have a 0 element? and is it the right test anyway?

Comment: It computes the expected frequency in the normal way I assume (I do not use python). It may or may not be the right test depending on your scientific question.

Comment: Each df corresponding to a group. I am trying to find in which case, df1 will have a different distribution than df3 (according to clusters). df2 distribution should be different than df1 but it's not necessary

Comment: A case where df1 will be mostly in cluster 1 while df3 in cluster 2

Comment: Re "I read that chi2_contingency couldn't be used if zero appears inside one or two of the cells:" I hope that's a misreading, because it's incorrect.  What matters are the *expected* values in the cells, not the actual values.  The chi-squared test will work fine in both your examples.  (Some software might complain, but the answer will still be informative.  Although the chi-squared p-value in the second example is too small, it still accurately indicates strong evidence of lack of independence.)

Comment: Thanks for responding, from what I know 80% of cells should be > 5 to be more accurate. I do not get errors but it seems like it "throw" some capable tables because of 1-5 appearance. I thought to use fishers (halton) but it's a mess with multiple different tables

Comment: Although what you know is common wisdom, it's not generally true.  One good way to assess whether a chi-squared p-value is accurate is to simulate the distribution of the chi-squared statistic.  (This is an option in some statistical software, making it easy to do.)

Comment: Thank you very much , will remember that